# Adding a label for an arrow in the middle of a diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following picture, but I would like the label $\tilde{f}$ of the arrow in the middle to sit on top of the arrow which I added after defining a path via a phantom arrow.

Are there any way to do this ?

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections}


\begin{document}

   \tikzset{%
    scalearrow/.style n args={3}{
     decoration={
      markings,
       mark=at position (1-#1)/2*\pgfdecoratedpathlength
         with {\coordinate (#2);},
       mark=at position (1+#1)/2*\pgfdecoratedpathlength
        with {\coordinate (#3);},
       },
     postaction=decorate,
     } 
    }

\begin{tikzcd}
{ } &{} &{Set} &{}  \\
{ } &{} &{\tilde{f}} &{}  \\
{A}  \ar[uurr,"!"] \ar[rrr,"f"']  \ar[rrr, shift left=5ex, phantom, scalearrow={0.1}{start}{end}] \ar[to path=(start) --(end), Rightarrow]  &{} &{}  &{B} \ar[uul, "\tilde{L}f"']&{}  \\
\end{tikzcd}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

but above image is drawn as pure TikZ picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 24mm and 12 mm
                    ]
\node (a) {$A$};
\node (s) [above right=of a] {Set};
\node (b) [below right=of s] {$B$};
%
\draw[->]   (a) edge ["!"] (s)
            (b) edge ["$\tilde{L}f$" '] (s)
            (a) edge ["$f$"] (b);
%            
\node (f) [below=9mm of s]  {$\stackrel{\tilde{f}}{\Rightarrow}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or with use `Longrightarrow` instead of `Rightarrow`:

[image]

and on the end with `tikz-cd`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzcd}
    &   &   \mathrm{Set}                            &   \\
    &   &   \stackrel{\tilde{f}}{\Longrightarrow}   &   \\
A  \ar[uurr,"!"] \ar[rrr,"f"']  
    &   &   &   B \ar[uul, "\tilde{L}f"']&{}            \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```